# How do you install SVN within Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, svn, version-control

how does one install SVN client within matlab 2014b?

There is an option in Preferences//General//Source Control, but it always shows 'None' although all of the installation are 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no special way of installing clients for SVN and Git. According to [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/select-or-disable-source-control-system.html)  support for both systems should be also enabled by default. The only possibility you actually have is either to enable MathWorks source control integration or not. If it's enabled, you should see current status of your files in "Current Folder" pane and you should have some options related to source control when you right click in that pane. Don't expect any fireworks there through. The interface is as basic as it can be.

[image]

[image: CurrentFolderPane]

Comment: thanks for the screenshot; however,  I under the Source Control in preferences, there is a combo box with only one option: None   Right below it says that 32 bit source control will not run on 64bit matlab.    Which version of Matlab are you running?  also, is source control a part of some toolbox that perhaps needs to be installed?

Comment: I'm using mostly 2017a but because of some 3rd party drivers which work only under 32bit version of Matlab I'm occasionally switching to 2015b. I didn't experience any issues with SVN nor Git under any of them but I also never tried 2014b. I also don't have any toolboxes which can have anything to do with source control. My guess is that maybe, since the feature was introduced in 2014b, there was some issue or additional prerequisite which is no longer mentioned in the documentation. Why don't you want to install newer version of Matlab and check if it solves the issue?